# Retrofit 2 onResponse fill an object in another class

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to use the values I get from my request but I can't use them because void onReponse method. Values I get is only staying in onResponse method. I know it is because it is void and I can't return anything but is there a way to fill an object with values I get?

Here is my ApiClient class:

```
public class ApiClient implements Callback<Map<String, Channel>> {

static final String BASE_URL = "some url";

public void start() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    RestInterface restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);

    Call<Map<String, Channel>> call = restInterface.getChannels();
    call.enqueue(this);

}

@Override
public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Map<String, Channel>> call, Response<Map<String, Channel>> response) {
    System.out.println(response.code());
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        Map<String, Channel> body = response.body();
        List<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>(body.values());
        for (Channel channel : body.values()) {
            System.out.println(channel.getSong());
        }
...
```

What I have to do is create Channel objects with the values I get from onResponse. I tried to use it in an another class like this:

```
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();

    apiClient.start();
```

but it still only works in onResponse. I need to create Channel objects like:

```
Channel channel = new Channel(channels(1));
```

this but in another class not in the ApiClient.

Answer (score 0):

Use callback interface to pass data to another class:

```
public interface ChannelCallback {

    void setChannels(Map<String, Channel> body);
}
```

In your ApiClient assign listener:

```
private ChannelCallback listener;

public void start(ChannelCallback listener) {

    this.listener = listener;

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

    RestInterface restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);

    Call<Map<String, Channel>> call = restInterface.getChannels();
    call.enqueue(this);

}
```

In OnResponse pass data via this listener:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Map<String, Channel>> call, 
Response<Map<String, Channel>> response) {
    System.out.println(response.code());
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        Map<String, Channel> body = response.body();
        listener.setChannels(body);
}
```

Not forget to implement ChannelCallback listener in class that calls ApiClient.start(this)

```
public SomeClass implements ChannelCallback{

    ...

    apiClient.start(this);

    ...

    @Override
    setChannels(Map<String, Channel> body){
    // logic here with data from body
    }

   ...

}
```

Comment: But how can I pass the data to new channel objects in the class that calls ApiClient?

Comment: check updated answer with implementation ChannelCallback interface

Comment: Hi again, did everything in your comment. I tried to implement it like this: '    public Radio(){
        apiClient.start(this);
        System.out.println(channel1.getSong());
    }' but now I get null pointer error. From the 'apiClient.start(this)'.

Comment: Looks like you not initialized apiClient

Comment: I know I asked too many questions but, here is the structure I use and still can't assign values: https://imgur.com/a/zhVwmtN Thanks for your help..

Comment: Are you sure what you get error at 'apiClient.start(this)', not sout(channel.getSong())?

.enqueue method is asynchronous, so it might call .getSong on null object, before Retrofit call onResponse and your callback that sets Channel obj

Comment: Sorry, I get the error at the point you say. How can make it not null? Any ideas?

Comment: Move your sout to callback method body, I sure it'll help you.

Avoid using objects which will be assigned from callback of async call before you definitely sure that callback are called, due to it might take some time to get response from server side, when your 'sout' calls instantly after you calls apiClient.start()

Comment: But here is the thing. In this class I will use 'getData' method to pass the Channels with value I get from body. So, I have to use objects in any case... Is there a way for this situation? Should I use a 'sleep' function (or any safer function/method you can suggest) for filling this channel objects?

Comment: I'm sorry for bad explanation, you can use object, but it might be null before your api-call get response from server and call your callback.

Comment: So, what can I do for make it not null? What method should I use?